# Changing a user's password within a script doesn't work

Tags: bash, debian, scripting, users

For reasons I want to change a user's password to a random one every X minutes using a script. It's a debian machine, the following script is started via `@reboot` in root's crontab and the script is running. Every X minutes the new password is written to the file specified in the script, however, the password is never changed.

```
#!/bin/bash
# change user's password to a random one on boot and every five minutes

while : ; do
    npasswd=$(pwgen 8 1)
    echo "$npasswd" > /root/current-user-passwd.txt
    usermod --password $(openssl passwd -1 "$npasswd") user
#   echo "$npasswd" | passwd user
#   usermod -p $(perl -e "print crypt("$npasswd","Q4")") user
    sleep 300
done
```

I have tried each of the three methods (the other two being commented out now), none work. However, when I copy the **entire** script and just paste it in a terminal to run it, it works perfectly fine. It just doesn't work in a script if it's started by cron.

Does anyone know what is going on here?
I've also tried `echo -n` by the way, same results. I've also tried to set `$npasswd` in the script to something fixed, just to test it, same results.

**Just to clearify:** I'm really looking for an answer that explains **why** this is working manually, but not in a script, not for an alternative way to change the password. Those methods **do work**, just not if the script is started by cron.

Output of the script with `set -o errexit -o nounset -o xtrace` on top:

```
+ :
++ pwgen 8 1
+ npasswd=eiZeed5u
+ echo eiZeed5u
++ openssl passwd -1 eiZeed5u
+ usermod --password '$1$EYRCYJXm$5XkrVNxdrYRzxBmcRwuXm0' user
+ sleep 300
```

Output of the above when started via cron's `@reboot`:

```
+ :
+ pwgen 8 1
+ npasswd=aizof5Ka
+ echo aizof5Ka
+ openssl passwd -1 aizof5Ka
+ usermod --password $1$KFrgibYH$e1dMUeF2AzTtSPExBjbXo1 user
/root/change-user-passwd.sh: 8: /root/change-user-passwd.sh: usermod: not found
```

Which makes the issue clear to me now, thanks @[l0b0](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/3645/l0b0)!

Comment: @l0b0 It's neither. I just needed a temporary password that works only once to login, once the login session ended the password should not work anymore. (Therefore, the every X minutes isn't exactly a requirement, I'd still like to know why this isn't working at all in a script while it does when run manually.)

Comment: @l0b0 But that wouldn't answer my actual question, that's why I didn't include the information. I'm sure there's another way to create on-time passwords (`passwd` itself has the `--expire` option), but I'd really like to know what's causing this particular issue of it working when run manually, but not inside of a script.

Comment: How are you checking that the password is not changed? Do you have more code to report what the password was changed to in your script?

Comment: @l0b0 I'm trying to physically log into the machine (lightdm login screen) with the new password, it doesn't work. Logging in via ssh as the `user` with the changed password doesn't work either. If I manually run those commands, it works. If I run it in the script, nothing's changed (the old password still works).

Comment: @l0b0 I'm sorry, I've just edited my question. Turns out if I run the script manually it does work. It just doesn't work when cron starts it. The file does get updated, but the password never changed. Do you still want me to do your suggestion?

Comment: Yes, it should give lots of information about what the problem is.

Comment: @l0b0 Done, appended the output to my question. If I want to log this information when the script is started by cron, stderr is what I write into a logfile, correct?

Comment: Did the script work or not when you ran it with those flags set?

Comment: @l0b0 It worked, when invoked using `bash script.sh`. I didn't try it using cron yet.

Comment: Your cron logs should go somewhere on your system, usually `/var/spool/cron/$USER`.

Comment: @l0b0 There's only the crontabs within that directory, I tried to use `&> logfile` to redirect it, but now cron doesn't seem to be able to start the script at all. If I run it manually (with the same redirection, same command as in crontab) it works and the output is written to the file, but cron doesn't even start the script now (checked with `ps aux`, it would always show up before). All I did was add the `set` line and the redirection. I checked `/var/log/syslog` - Cron did execute the command. I'm not sure what happened at all.

Comment: @l0b0 Alright, that was my fault. `Cron` is using `sh` instead of `bash` and `&>` is a bash thing. Now the issue is clear, thank you so much. I assume the same issue (cron having a different shell and `$PATH`) is causing `usermod` not to be found? `usermod`'s binary is indeed not in `/usr/bin`, but in `/usr/sbin`. Do you want to leave a full answer so I can accept it? **Edit:** Confirmed. Supplying full path for `usermod` within the script fixed it. Everything works as expected now.

Answer (score 4):

According to: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714915/using-the-passwd-command-from-within-a-shell-script

`echo "$npasswd" | passwd --stdin user`

or

`echo "user:$npasswd" | chpasswd`

will be good for you.

Comment: My `passwd` doesn't have the `--stdin` option. The pipe of the second command seems weird to me. Why pipe echo to the command when `$npasswd` is provided to `chpasswd` directly? I've tried it on the command-line: `chpasswd: line 1: missing new password`

Comment: I think I got it from `man chpasswd`. I have proposed an edit to your answer of the correct usage for `chpasswd`, may you please accept it? It works manually, I'll try it in a script now.

Comment: Thanks for correction! And I wish helps your problem solve.